# TypeScript get generic property

Tags: typescript, generics

My code is Here

The type1 I can the result I want, but I got a type check error, even I suppress with @ts-ignore, it still popup errors.
The type2 is legal, but doesn't work.

I thought may in T[Field['name']], the code 'Field['name']' isn't consider as a value?

```js
interface Req{
  stringField:string,
  dateField:string,
  numberField:number
}

type Field<T>={
  name: keyof T;
  // get T['name'],base on T['name']'s type,return values  

  // @ts-ignore 
  // type 1
  type: T.Field<T>['name'] extends number?'number': 'string'|'date'
  // type 2
  // type: T[Field<T>['name']] extends number?'number': 'string'|'date'
}

const arr:Field<Req>[]=[
  {name:'stringField',type:'string'},
  {name:'dateField',type:'date'},
  {name:'numberField',type:'number'}
]
```

I want to either supress the error or the legal code working.

Comment: If you want to get `name` and `type` property from generic `T`, you should apply appropriate constraint and then use square bracket notation. Example: `type Field<T extends {name:string, type:string}>=T['name']`

Answer (score 1):

The following type `Field` returns a union of all valid types by mapping each key in the passed interface to the valid object type for that key/name and then creating a union of values/types from the mapped type

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQI4G8BQzkDOYUoA5gGLAQA2AJgFxEkikA0eytcklNDTZdvhABXALYAjaLzr1Rk6DgC+OHGACeABxQzaAHgAqAPmQBeZLnwBtANLJQyANYR1AexjIDAXXoWOwuDEIXxsAbn9kDW1fA1svZAgAD0gQWgJkeSkoZAB+ZAByTOh85F98gRZ8gB98rkh8jhUlK2c3D29VKJR0DF108109HqNwgHpR-GQAPRzVBFcQImQ4KChfQeGrePMrDiwQQODy4jJdfNYu+mPmUnylIQsDoKu6iDOLrSPXu4f9w6uilB3pcCoC7jgvEA)

```
interface Req{
  stringField:string,
  dateField:string,
  numberField:number
}

type Field<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    name: K;
    type: T[K] extends number ? 'number' : 'string'|'date'
  }
}[keyof T]

const arr: Field<Req>[] = [
  {name:'stringField',type:'string'},
  {name:'dateField',type:'date'},
  {name:'numberField',type: 'number'}
]
```